# Paging in AngularJS with MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a table using ng-repeat and I want to implement paging below that table.

Controller:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    $scope.GetAllData = function () {
        $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:12345/Employee/Get_AllEmployee"
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.employees = response.data;
        }, function () {
            alert("Error Occured!");
        })
    };
```

View:

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" style="margin:5px 5px 5px 5px">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="GetAllData()" class="divList">
        <table cellpadding="12" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>ID</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Name</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>City</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Contact</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>EmailID</b>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        <b>Actions</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="Emp in filteredEmp | filter: queryText">
                <td>
                    {{Emp.CustomerID}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Emp.Name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Emp.Address}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Emp.Mobileno}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Emp.EmailID}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Update" ng-click="UpdateEmp(Emp)" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" ng-click="DeleteEmp(Emp)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve pagination?

Comment: I tried using BootstrapUI and dirPagination but couldn't make it through.

Comment: Can you add plunker or code sample of same to analyze issue you are facing

Comment: I don't know how to create plunker.

Comment: you can follow this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702042/how-to-use-ui-bootstrap-pagination-for-a-table-generated-using-ng-repeat

Comment: first, have you implemented pagination in your API?, I mean its better to implement pagination in your API, instead of retrieving all the info and implement pagination on the front-end, I recommend the first approach.

Comment: This is the MVC controller-
public JsonResult Get_AllEmployee()
        {
            using(TestDBEntities obj=new TestDBEntities())
            {
            List<Employee> emp=obj.Employees.ToList();
            return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
how can I paginate in this?

Comment: Don't put code in comments.  It's unreadable.  Put code in the question.

Comment: @CodeUnderflow : use this link https://plnkr.co/edit/L4nDcbXlvnE2nHWdoe3L?p=preview